# Notation for half-integers

Tags: notation

I'm wondering if there is any sort of colloquial notation for the set of half integers (i.e.
 $\{ \frac{n}{2} \mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$), or any sort of set of fractions of integers, (i.e.
 $\{\frac{n}{a}\mid $  $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ is some rational number$\}$). I'd also consider adopting a-not-so-colloquial notation. Thanks.

Comment: "[Half-integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-integer)" usually refers to $\frac n2$ only when $n$ is *odd*.

Comment: Ah you are right! Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most people would understand the notation $\frac{a}{b}\mathbb{Z}$ for the set $\bigl\{\frac{na}{b} \mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\bigr\}$. Intuitively, this notation indicates to me "take the set $\mathbb{Z}$, and scale it by $\frac{a}{b}$", which produces the correct result.

Alternatively, I think the notation $\mathbb{Z}\frac{a}{b}$ is just as good. Intuitively, it indicates to me "take the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $\frac{a}{b}$", which again is the correct set.

More generally, given an integral domain $R$ and its fraction field $K$, a common notation for the principal [fractional ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal) generated by some $x\in K^\times$ is $xR$ (I've also seen $Rx$, and $(x)$ when the context is clear). See for example [this blurb](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/idealfactor.pdf#page=3) by Keith Conrad (about midway down the page).

Here is an example of the other two alternatives, in Bourbaki's Algebra:

[image]

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this, and I'm not sure I would understand it without an explanation.  (I agree that it is quite clear, if the explanation you gave is included.)

Comment: Wikipedia says for half-integers to use $\mathbb{Z} +\frac{1}{2}$, but I like your notation better, since it extends to the set of rational numbers. I'll go ahead and use it, at least for my notes. Edit: It's worth noting that wikipedia's notation lets us translate the entire set.

Comment: @PatEugene: $\mathbb Z+\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb Z\frac12$ are different sets.  Your question appears to be about the latter.